# Python Script No Result

Tags: python, function

Prior to modifying the sys.argv input sections this script was working with a static file providing input ... not for some reason that I cannot figure out ... when I run the script with two arguments ./scriptname vuln_banners  it just exits.

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
import socket
import sys
import os
def retBanner(ip, port):
    try:
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect((ip, port))
        banner = s.recv(1024)
        return banner
    except:
        return
def checkVulns(banner, filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.strip('\n') in banner:
            print '[-] Server is vulnerable:'+ banner.strip('\n')
def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        filename = sys.argv[1]
        if not os.path.isfile(filename):
            print '[-] ' + filename + ' does not exist'
            exit(0)
            if not os.access(filename, os.R_OK):
                print '[-] '+ filename + 'Access Denied'
                exit(0)
    else:
        print '[-] Usage: ' + str(sys.argv[0]) + '<vuln-filename>'
        exit(0)
        portList = [21,22,25,80,110]
        for x in range(1, 100):
            ip = '172.17.1.'+ str(x)
            for port in portList:
                print 'Checking ' + str(ip) + ' on port '+ str(port)
                banner = retBanner(ip, port)
                if banner:
                    print '[+] ' + ip + ': ' + banner
                    checkVulns(banner, filename)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Well, that's what `exit(0)` does. I'd also be careful with downloading "exploit" scripts and running them on your computer.

Comment: You have screwed up your indentation from the looks of it.  Your `for x in range` line only runs if the `len(sys.argv) != 2` which I am pretty sure is not what you want.

Comment: blender, it's not an exploit script just a simple banner checking vulnerability scanner I wrote to try and improve on python. Thanks for the obvious on the exit(0). I was more confused about my indentation which sherry was able to answer for me.